# Core file truncated for a dpdk application running inside pod/container

Tags: centos7, coredump

I am running a dpdk application inside a container (running in the Kubernetes cluster). When the application crashes (segmentation fault), I get a truncated core file. ulimit -c is set to unlimited, there is no disk space issue. The expected core file is around 10 GB in size. Rarely do I get a complete core file. On tracing in the kernel code, I see that the dump_interrupted function is returning true (fs/coredump.c).

OS: Cent OS 7
Kernel version used: 3.10.0-693.2.2.rt56.623.el7.x86_64

Is there any way to increase the time for core collection in the kernel?

Comment: Since your application is running in a docker, is there a chance the directory or file been accessed from the container does not have read/write permission? Can you share the information 1) docker privilege and folder shared? and 2) some information into which specific area or files truncation is happening? I also assume disk space is local and not NFS or Network mounted area too.

Comment: Can you please check RLIMIT_CORE or RLIMIT_FSIZE  value using API `getrlimit` to ensure you have more than 10GB set for collecting large file (within docker environment, yes you have pointed out you have set `ulimit -c unlimit`) But just to cross-check if it is reflected inside docker too.)

Comment: `LIM_INFINITY = 18446744073709551615
Core limits:
    Soft=18446744073709551615
    Hard=18446744073709551615
File limits:
    Soft=18446744073709551615
    Hard=18446744073709551615`

Comment: Local disk is used for file storage. Related to permission, there is no issue. A core file is generated, but it is truncated. If core_pattern is set to 0x1f, I will get a full core file (around 1.5GB size). But, if I used the core_pattern value of 0x7f, the core file gets truncated. In gdb, I get messages like "**core.myapp.1631539785.348 is truncated: expected core file size >= 10760261632, found: 2300489728**"

Comment: thanks for the information, is your core file generated in `/var/core`? Can you cross-check the partition size and usage with help `df -kh` to cross check if the portion holding `/var/core` is forcing the truncate? note: if it  is not in `/var/core` can you cross-check the partition where core file is formed is causing truncate? Can you please share information `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` Maybe the truncation is happening because values are not set here

Comment: I have updated an answer, can you please try it out and check if it solves the issues. If yes, accept and upvote to close the current question.

Comment: thanks for the update @PrahladaHerle, I will remove it as it has not solved your problem. Please do update with the answer, as it is an interesting problem.